# Adding a DbSet adds an unexpected column to existing model in EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Im using EntityFrameworkCore.

I've got a Reference data table with a discriminator

```
CREATE TABLE ReferenceData(
  Id uniqueidentifier,
  Discriminator varchar(255),
  Value varchar(255),
  SecondaryValue varchar(255),
   CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ReferenceData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
  [Id] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And my DbContext maps this

```
public class WeddingDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<WeddingEvent> WeddingEvents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<StarterChoice> StarterChoices { get; set; }

    public DbSet<MainChoice> MainChoices { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DessertChoice> DessertChoices { get; set; }

    public WeddingDbContext(DbContextOptions<WeddingDbContext> dbContextOptions)
        : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ReferenceData>()
            .HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator")
            .HasValue<WeddingEvent>("WeddingEvent")
            .HasValue<StarterChoice>("StarterChoice")
            .HasValue<MainChoice>("MainChoice")
            .HasValue<DessertChoice>("DessertChoice");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

When I use this it works perfectly, as I would like it to.

```
using (WeddingDbContext context = new WeddingDbContext(contextOptions))
{
    foreach (WeddingEvent weddingEvent in context.WeddingEvents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"weddingevent: {weddingEvent.Value}");
    }
}
```

My problem is when I add a new class to the DbContext, it starts to expect a new column in the WeddingEvent model and I can't work out why this is.

```
public class WeddingDbContext : DbContext
{
    // This is new
    public DbSet<Invite> Invites { get; set; }

    public DbSet<WeddingEvent> WeddingEvents { get; set; }

    // The rest of the DbSets shown above here
}
```

Here is the new Invite Class

```
public class Invite
{
    internal Invite(
        IEnumerable<WeddingEvent> weddingEvents)
    {
        WeddingEvents = weddingEvents.ToList();
    }

    protected Invite()
    {
    }

    public virtual ICollection<WeddingEvent> WeddingEvents { get; private set; }
}
```

The SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Discriminator], [r].[Value], [r].[InviteId]
FROM [ReferenceData] AS [r]
WHERE [r].[Discriminator] = N'WeddingEvent'
```

Why is trying to select InviteId? Can anyone help?

Comment: You have introduced `one-to-many` relationship between `Invite` and `WeddingEvent`, hence EF (and database in general) needs a foreign key column in the `WeddingEvent` table (or in the base table in your case).

Comment: Thanks, I created a class which has Invite and WeddingEvent in.  Created a many to many table